# CSS - Horizontal Nested List wrapping out of order

Tags: css, list, submenu

I am trying to fix an issue with my CSS where I am trying to create a three tiered horizontal list.

The intended result is that it looks like a three tiered menu.

When the list gets too long, instead of creating wrapping directly below itself, it wraps below the submenu. This is very obvious once the Horizontal window size becomes smaller (1024 instead of 1920).

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GI4O70ZXQWZ9

Above is the link to the sample code.

White is the main menu, blue is the submenu and green is another sub-submenu.